# Can't find Fill Hole in MeshLab

Tags: meshlab

I have "Fill Hole" tool missing on meshlab. I downloaded it from their official website.

Does anyone know why? Please help. Thank you!

Jihang

Comment: Have you looked at the menubar? If it is not between the "Arc3D importer" and "Manipulators tool", could you maybe share a printscreen so that we can see what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The filter was buggy. Now there is the "close hole " filter, under the "remeshing..." submenu and you can use this one instead.